# How do you hard-fork a Clique PoA chain to use new validators?

Tags: poa, clique, aura

Imagine you've got a running PoA chain using Clique PoA with Geth. If everything is running normally, you can propose additions and removals of validators and the existing validators will vote on the changes. However, let's suppose the majority of the existing validators is misbehaving and will not cooperate with the validator change you want, but people using the chain are agreed on a last good block and prepared to carry on with the existing state, but using new validators.

It appears that if you were running Aura with Parity, you could change your genesis.json to add the new validators from a particular block:
https://openethereum.github.io/Validator-Set.html#multi-set
This will obviously appear invalid to anyone who hasn't upgraded their genesis.json as of that block, but let's assume that's OK.

Can you do something similar with Geth and Clique? Alternatively, is there a way to bootstrap a new chain with a fresh genesis.json, but import the state from the previous chain as the initial state for the new chain?